# How to draw endo-bicyclo[2.2.1]hept-5-ene-2,3-dicarboxylic anhydride on ChemDraw?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, molecules, software

I'm struggling to draw *endo*-bicyclo[2.2.1]hept-5-ene-2,3-dicarboxylic anhydride on ChemDraw. I currently have this:

[image: bicycloheptene anhydride]

How can I draw it in the chair conformation side on view? I know what it is supposed to look like, just not sure how to draw it on ChemDraw.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there is no chair conformation in this bicycle framework. It is always have a boat-confirmation with the two edges of the boat to make the bridge head. Following is the step-by-step guidance to draw *exo*-form of the compound on ChemDraw:

[image: A way to draw endo-bicyclo[2.2.1]hept-5-ene-2,3-dicarboxylic anhydride]

On side panel of the ChemDraw file, you can find various different bicyclo frameworks. Carefully choose the correct bicycloheptane and click on the drawing space. Then follow the instruction to get what you want.